# Qt 4.7 Emitting a signal to a specific thread

Tags: qt

I have several client GUI windows all derived from `QMainWindow`. Each window is potentially doing a different task but all are requesting data from a central cache implemented as a `QThread`.

All the clients connect to the same `slot` in the data cache and then emit `signal`s to prompt the data cache to do something. The `signal`s to the data cache get queued so the data cache only ever does one thing at a time.

When the data cache completes it needs to inform the correct client that the thing it was doing has completed. My immediate thought is to emit a `signal` to the requesting client about the completion. This would mean connecting to a specific client's `slot` and then emitting a `signal` to it.

Do I have to do connect and then disconnect to the client? I'm aware of the `QObject::sender()` function to get the supplier. Is there some way of emitting a signal to that sender (client) only? Or is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: - Where are you calling `QObject::connect` in order to form the links between your clients and the data cache - from the client objects or from the data cache?

- What do you mean by the title of this question - what are the specific threads that your app is creating?

- What does a client object need to do on receipt of a 'data cache completion' signal, by which I mean how much data does the client need to retrieve from the cache?

Comment: To clarify @sjwarner comments. I am calling QObject::connect from the client objects, that is the QMainwindow derived objects. I have been assuming that each one of these represents a separate GUI thread. The amount of data returned depends, it can be small or large amounts depending on what the data cache has been asked to do. I am using pointers into the data cache to access this data. The data being is accessed is static once it has been initialised and hence there is no locking mechanism. So far I have had no conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

There may be simpler approaches you can take to resolve your problem.  For example, I would consider looking into the [QtConcurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qtconcurrent.html) framework.  Alternately, you might also re-architect your design such that the client first connects to a "finished" signal on the cache prior to asking the cache to do anything.  Failing all of that, you might also consider relying on the [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) function (for either your client or your cache).  This function allows you to call an arbitrary method on an arbitrary QObject (provided that you have a pointer to it) using arbitrary generic arguments (in a way that's thread-safe).

If you use the `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` approach, there are a few of drawbacks you should be aware of.  Firstly, you have to invoke the method using its string name, which means that you won't find out at compile time if you're using the wrong name.  Secondly, since your clients have a different thread affinity than the central cache, there's a chance that the client will have been destroyed when the cache invokes the method on them (though perhaps in your case, this won't be a problem for you).  Finally, you may not want your cache to have any knowledge of the names of the methods that it must execute on its client.

I don't have any way of getting around the first drawback (I'm not sure if this is going to be handled differently in the upcoming Qt 5.0 release).  As far as the second and third problems, I would recommend creating an object that encapsulates a reference to a method -- something like the following:

```
class MethodReference
{
   MethodReference(QObject* object, const QString& methodName);

   ...

   bool invoke(QGenericArgument val0 = QGenericArgument(),
               QGenericArgument val1 = QGenericArgument(),
               ...
               QGenericArgument val9 = QGenericArgument());

private:
   QPointer<QObject> mObject;
   QString mMethod;
};
```

You would then pass this object to your cache from the client.  The cache then calls invoke on this object.

Note the use of `QPointer` -- this gives you a thread-safe way of checking if your object has been destroyed before you try to invoke a method on it.  Since I've done this before, I'll also let you know that versions of Qt prior to 4.8 had a [bug in `QPointer`](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-16005) that would cause a crash in a multi-threaded context.  Use a more recent version of Qt if you want to do this.

I hope this was clear.

Comment: Thank you @RA. I have to confess that the meta object sub-system has till now been a bit mysterious to me, so far. I have used it as little as possible to date but having seen your answer has prompted me to look at it again more closely. It is really very interesting with the QMetaObject::invokeMethod making me think of Java